# Sql joins query returning records of unspecified fields values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Good day guys, I have three tables and I doing a JOIN to return records from these tables. I want to return the scores of subjects a student have, and I’m finding the results based upon the student id and class id. This is my query:

```
SELECT period_one.student_id, period_one.subject_id,  period_one.score, period_two.score,period_three.score, first_exam.score
        from period_one

LEFT JOIN period_two
ON period_one.subject_id = period_two.subject_id

LEFT JOIN period_three 
on period_one.subject_id = period_three.subject_id

LEFT JOIN first_exam 
on period_one.subject_id = first_exam.subject_id
WHERE period_one.student_id = 1 AND period_one.class_id = 2
```

I want the query to return this result:
[image]
Everything works fine and I get the desire result that I want if and only if there is a single student id in the tables(period one, period two and period three). But if there are two(2) student ids in the tables(period one, period two and period three) which will always be the case, it return this instead.

[image]

I realize the only way for me to get the desire result that I want is to update my where clause like this:

```
WHERE period_one.student_id = 1 AND period_one.class_id = 2
AND period_two.student_id = 1 AND period_two.class_id = 2
AND period_three.student_id = 1 AND period_three.class_id = 2
```

I think this states that the student id and class id have to be true for the three tables and if not it returns no result.

Even though it does work somehow if I update my where clause with the code above I don't want to do it that way because that returns subjects grades for other students. Are there other ways that I can accomplish this without modifying my where clause like I did? Let me know if I should var dump() what I'm getting from the query.

Here are my tables:

```
table period_one {
    id int AUTO INCREMENT,
    student_id int, ## foreign key
    subject_id int, ## foreign key
    class_id int, ## foreign key
    score double
}

table period_two {
    id int AUTO INCREMENT,
    student_id int, ## foreign key
    subject_id int, ## foreign key
    class_id int, ## foreign key
    score double
}

table period_three {
    id int AUTO INCREMENT,
    student_id int, ## foreign key
    subject_id int, ## foreign key
    class_id int, ## foreign key
    score double
}
```

I'm not confident if I'm doing this the right way here, so please let me know if there are better ways I can do this or if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join on your `FKs` as well

```
SELECT period_one.student_id, period_one.subject_id,  period_one.score, 
       period_two.score,period_three.score, first_exam.score
FROM period_one    
LEFT JOIN period_two ON 
             period_one.subject_id = period_two.subject_id 
             AND period_one.student_id = period_two.student_id     
LEFT JOIN period_three ON 
             period_one.subject_id = period_three.subject_id 
             AND period_one.student_id = period_three.student_id

LEFT JOIN first_exam ON 
             period_one.subject_id = first_exam.subject_id
             AND period_one.student_id = first_exam.student_id
WHERE period_one.student_id = 1 
AND period_one.class_id = 2
```

And consider joining on `class_id` as well if you want to get correct results for a `Class` like so:

```
SELECT period_one.student_id, period_one.subject_id,  period_one.score, 
       period_two.score,period_three.score, first_exam.score
FROM period_one    
LEFT JOIN period_two ON 
             period_one.subject_id = period_two.subject_id 
             AND period_one.student_id = period_two.student_id 
             AND period_one.class_id = period_two.class_id    
LEFT JOIN period_three ON 
             period_one.subject_id = period_three.subject_id 
             AND period_one.student_id = period_three.student_id
             AND period_one.class_id = period_three.class_id
LEFT JOIN first_exam ON 
             period_one.subject_id = first_exam.subject_id
             AND period_one.student_id = first_exam.student_id
             AND period_one.class_id = first_exam.class_id 
WHERE period_one.student_id = 1 
AND period_one.class_id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Stephen I got it working. I mean how did you even see that? Believe me I jealous that vision. Thanks once again.

Comment: Is there a way that I can be more thankful, a blog to follow or post to like?

Answer (score 0):

a SELECT DISTINCT could be the way...

```
SELECT DISTINCT period_one.student_id, period_one.subject_id,  period_one.score, period_two.score,period_three.score, first_exam.score
        from period_one

LEFT JOIN period_two
ON period_one.subject_id = period_two.subject_id

LEFT JOIN period_three 
on period_one.subject_id = period_three.subject_id

LEFT JOIN first_exam 
on period_one.subject_id = first_exam.subject_id
WHERE period_one.student_id = 1 AND period_one.class_id = 2
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` should always be the last resort, first one must try to identify the problem.